# Connect to local xml File and create button from results

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a xml file name **Albums** situated in my Assets folder of my UWP

I then have a **SplitView** with a **VariableSizedWrapGrid** attached that I would get information from the XML file and create a button for each item accordingly. Such as **Image Source/Title/Year**.

Any examples would be very welcome, as I've not done much c# programming in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the xml file, you could use the [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.xml.dom) APIs.

Here's an official [XML DOM sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XmlDocument) for your reference. See the scenario 3 & 4.

In your case, you said that the xml file is in 'Assets' folder. Then, you first need to get the xml file from `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation`. Please note that the files in the location of installed package are read-only, you could only read it.

After you get the xml file, then you could load it by the relevant APIs.

```
var folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("your.xml");
var doc = await Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file);
```